# SSH login to same machine with ssh-key keeps prompting for password

Tags: ssh, centos7

I want user 'redmine' to login to the same machine via ssh without a password. However it always asks for a password.
I am on Centos 7, the key has no password.

Content of redmine's home-dir:

```
drwx------  redmine redmine   ~/.ssh

-rwx------  redmine redmine   ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub      
-rwx------  redmine redmine   ~/.ssh/id_rsa         
-rw-------  redmine redmine   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys  (same content as id_rsa.pub)
```

*(I need this to automatically fetch git repositories also stored on the same machine. Suggestions for different approaches are welcome)*

Now I type
`ssh redmine@134.255.217.111 -vvv` (when already logged in as user redmine in the shell)

result:

```
[redmine@/opt/redmine> ssh redmine@134.255.217.111 -vvv
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "134.255.217.111" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 134.255.217.111 [134.255.217.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 134.255.217.111:22 as 'redmine'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/opt/redmine/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /opt/redmine/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 134.255.217.111
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:RagTUBrGcVX310yTRIfOWqDOhqDi4Un/79pnUOlApIY
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/opt/redmine/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /opt/redmine/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 134.255.217.111
debug1: Host '134.255.217.111' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /opt/redmine/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55f227cd00a0)
debug2: key: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1001)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1001)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /opt/redmine/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
redmine@134.255.217.111's password:
```

Content of /var/log/secure

```
Feb  4 00:22:14 vps-ts su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user redmine by john(uid=0)
Feb  4 00:22:22 vps-ts sshd[20705]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /opt/redmine
```

**Unrecommended** workaround:
sshd_config:

```
StrictMode no
```

Comment: This setup looks OK to me. If this login fails, check the openssh server log entries in `/var/log/secure` or the journal.

Comment: The log entries does not show anything regarding my problem. First entry on login attempt:  `Accepted password for redmine from [myIP] port 57810 ssh2`

Comment: Doesn't the .ssh directory need execute permissions? Try a chmod 700 on the .ssh folder, and 600 on the authorized_keys file.

Comment: please try verbose mode, e.g. `ssh redmine@127.0.0.1 -vvv` and update the question with the output

Comment: worst case, start over, e.g. `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub redmine@127.0.0.1` . You may want to delete authorized_keys, unless it contains other users keys. ssh-copy-id will get it right, first time. You must do this as the user redmine of course, apologies if stating the obvious.

Comment: Jepper, followed your instructions, still get the password prompt. Please don't hestitate to state the obvious, as I am obviously out of knowledge.

Comment: The relevant log entries in the server side will appear _before_ the line saying "Accepted password for redmine". The client side debug messages are useless.

Comment: It says "bad ownership or modes". However the .ssh dir has 700, and authorized keys has 600. I set StrictMode to false to overcome the error since I am out of ideas.. Thank you anyways for helping me to get there!!

Comment: Yes, and it tells you which directory has bad ownership or modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ssh log tells you what the problem is:

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /opt/redmine
```

Notice that it tells you exactly which directory it is concerned with: In this case, it's the home directory itself.

The user's home directory cannot be group or world writable, and must be owned by the user whose home directory it is supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you michael! It appears, the user's home directory had the same owner/group set. Having it being owned by redmine:redmine fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the users home directory (in your case /opt/redmine) is not writable by other users?
If it is writable by other users, you might want to deny them by using the command

```
chmod og-w /opt/redmine
```

Source: sshd man page

> ```
>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
>         (...)
>
>         If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, **or the user's home directory** are >writable by other users, then the file could be modified or
>         replaced by unauthorized users.  In this case, sshd will not allow it to >be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to “no”.
> ```

Answer (score -2):

you have to put the contents of id_rsa.pub in authorized_keys (without any spaces/newlines), but i think what prohibits your connection is probably that you might need to edit your sshd_config file and edit this line:

```
PermitRootLogin = yes   (it should be set to no by default)
```

then bounce your sshd, otherwise it will also prompt for a password.
access rights on files can also be problematic if permissions are too open

Comment: The config was already set, the content of id_rsa.pub is also content of authorized_keys. It still asks for a password :(

Comment: what are the permissions of the two files ?

Comment: Permissions of .ssh and all files in it are 600 (-rw-------  1 redmine root)

Comment: i think the authorized_keys need to be 644 and not 600 (600 is for id_rsa only)

Comment: Still not working, when authorized_keys have 644. May this be due to a different configuration setting?

Comment: yes in sshd_config you have other important parameters such as PasswordAuthentication. also, you are using only the redmine user right ? from redmine to redmine ?

Comment: I am using multiple users to connect to the machine with ssh. But only redmine user needs to connect (only from localhost) to localhost without a password.

Comment: and these users have access to the private key (id_rsa) of root ? you need to understand that every user you want to connect from (A, B, C) have to have the contents of its public key (every user should have an id_rsa & id_rsa.pub in its home dir) published in the "target user's authorized_keys" file.

Comment: for example if user abc wants to connect to root@localhost, you need to ensure that the /home/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.pub contents is copied to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys. get it ?

Comment: There is nothing in the question about logging in as root.

Comment: I simply want to have user redmine to connect to localhost by "ssh redmine@127.0.0.1" without a password, whereas any other user can connect whatever method I provide. This should not affect behaviour of other users using ssh on that machine.

Comment: I think what oliverg means is that if I am logged in the shell as another user than redmine, this user has to have the private key for redmine in it's ssh-directory for password free ssh-login. right?